# Exporting spatialite view to shapefile from QGIS modifies original data types?

Tags: qgis, export, spatialite, fields-attributes

We have a spatialite .sqlite database where we have views which are nicely rendered by QGis, with all the symbols and everything!

There are integer fields on the view which are based on fields of the sqlite database which are also integers, however, when I try to export to a shapefile, using right-click 'Save As', the shapefile created has converted some of the fields on strings.

I double checked the view, casting explicitly the fields as integers (they are on the right side of the field on the attribute table :-) ) and still the shapefile converts this fields on strings.

I also tried directly on spatialite_gui, right click on the geom field, and exporting to shapefile with the same results.

I tried to downloading the ogr2gui but not option for exporting views, only tables.

Does someone how to force the shapefile to get a specific data type?

I am using QGIS 2.2.

Comment: Please update the the question to include the exact table definition and the dBase result.  It's quite possible that the discrepancy is due to an inability of the 1980's dBaseIII format to support the requested datatype.

Comment: More probably it is caused by the fact that sqlite does not really have strict types http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761563/sqlite-data-types. View may make things more complicated. Could you create a minimal sqlite db with a few features and views for examination?

Comment: Hi, do you mean a listing of fields and its  types of the sqlite, the view and the shapefile ??